# HTTP 500 Internal Server error when uploading files

Tags: php, apache, http, file-upload, cpanel

This is driving me crazy. I have a php file upload script hosted on CPanel-controlled web hosting, whenever I try to upload files larger than 3-4 MB I get a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. Now, I did create a php.ini file in my public_html directory and did specify:

```
upload_max_filesize = 250M
post_max_size = 250M
```

and indeed, when I execute `phpinfo()` I see that both of these values are set and active. When I run the exact same script on my local wamp configuration it works.

I'm out of options here. What could it be? Memory exhaustion? Highly doubt it.

**EDIT:**

Weird: when I go to `PHP Configuration` in CPanel, `upload_max_filesize` is set to `2MB` even though `phpinfo()` shows `250MB`. So apparently it is blocked server-wide in WHM? Why does it say otherwise in phpinfo?

Comment: Cpanel has a log viewer if I recall correctly. Check it out.

Comment: and it shows nothing, even though it is active.

Comment: I assume you mean the "Error Log" feature.

Comment: Yes... Apache normally displays the exact error on its error log. If that's not the case, it's possible that PHP is not configured to log/display error messages.

Comment: It does show some irrelevant logs, so presumably it is active. Nothing related to this particular case though

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992376/how-to-set-upload-max-filesize-in-htaccess - you may be able to override with .htaccess - also 250M is kind of big, try something a bit lower.

Comment: Every 500 should leave a detailed error message in the log, check it out

Comment: @tremor - tried everything suggested there, didn't work - same HTTP 500.

Comment: It *must* somewhere - if not in the logs you're seeing, then somewhere else. Might be worth asking the hosting company

Comment: Couple questions: 1. What OS is your site running, NIX or Win?  2. Is your site using a CMS like Wordpress or Drupal (those often have their own settings independant of cpanel and php.ini?  3. Who is your host, they may have some FAQs or info in their support that could help?

Comment: @tremor  1. Nix, 2. None, just one .php file with simple upload code in it. 3. Local ISP, I am trying to contact them for the past several hours with no luck.

Comment: @astralmaster - 1 more question, probably should have asked this one first... is the directory in which your files are being saved into on the server set to WRITEABLE?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this may have been answered on stack already:

You need to increase FcgidMaxRequestLen in httpd.conf file

use something like

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen 67108864
```

[php upload and internal server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669712/php-upload-and-internal-server-error)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to httpd.conf file.

Comment: Besides, I have checked and - I am able to upload files of max. 2 MB. and I can clearly see that limitation in CPanel PHP Configuration. So I doubt it has something to do with Apache.